# Dompdf max-height not working

Tags: dompdf, css

I try to create a price tag with dom pdf. The price tag consists of some div containers. One of these containers have a max-height, but this is not working. Because if I change the text of this container to a text with 200 words instead of 100, the price tag is scaling higher.
But I need a fixed height.

Is this an issue?

HTML:

```
<html>

    <head>

<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="tag">
    <div class="header">
    Product
    </div>
    <div class="article">
    <div class="info">Lorem sd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>

    </div>
    <div class="barcode">
    <p>Barcode</p>
    </div>



</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.tag {
    border-style: solid;
    min-width:11.5cm;
    max-width:11.5cm;
    max-height:3.5cm;
    margin:0.1cm;
    padding:0.1cm;
}
.header {
    min-width:11.5cm;
    max-width:11.5cm;
    font-size:35px;
    font-weight:bold;
}

.article {
    min-width:11.5cm;
    max-width:11.5cm;

}

.info {

  float:left;
  text-align:left;
  min-width:7.5cm;
  max-width:7.5cm;
  min-height:2.0cm;
  max-height:2.0cm;
  font-size:10px;
}

.barcode {
    text-align:center;
    min-width:11.5cm;
    max-width:11.5cm;
}`
```

The .info class and the .tag class are important. max-width is working correctly.

Comment: Can you provide some HTML and CSS please so we can better understand what's going on

Comment: I added my HTML and CSS. (I know there are some duplicates of CSS attributes, it is only for testing)

Comment: Seeing that your `min-` and `max-height` are the same, why not just use `height` ?

Comment: Yes, but sometimes the result was different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want fix height, just use `height` and give it a fixed value and use `overflow: hidden` to hide extra data.

Change in CSS:

```
.info {
  overflow: hidden;
  float:left;
  text-align:left;
  min-width:7.5cm;
  max-width:7.5cm;
  height:35px;
  font-size:10px;
}
```

See working example here: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3fejr/1/)

Comment: Okay I will try it. My only problem was that my solution is not working in Dompdf, but in browser like chrome, firefox etc.

Comment: No change, same result. The `height` is scaling.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. It is a little bit confusing.
`max-height` and `min-height` are not working. If I use a solution only with height it is correctly working.

@Aayushi Jain:
Your solution is working, the only problem was that my browser uses the old css from cache instead of the new version.

Comment: Also, yes, max-height and min-height aren't fully supported. I believe they work OK on images, but not block objects.